# URLSession's Data Task returning Nil when I try to conform the object to Identifiable protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-protocols, urlsession, jsondecoder

I'm trying to run a simple http request to Spotify's api to get the recent played tracks

```
"https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played?limit=2&before=1676369852305"
```

Everything works and I do get the result back, but when I add the *Identifiable* protocol with **id** variable to my struct objects the decoder fails (nil).
(I want to conform to Identifiable because I need to use the data in a List/ForEach loop

Here's my code

```
//objects
struct Recent: Codable {   //or Codable, Identifiable
    //let id: UUID?
    let items: [Item]?
    let next: String?
    let limit: Int?
    let href: String?
}
struct Item: Codable {    //or Codable, Identifiable
    // let id: UUID?
    let track: Track?
    let played_at: String?
}
struct Track: Codable {    //or Codable, Identifiable  
    //let id: String?  
    let name: String?
    let popularity: Int?
    let trackNumber: Int?
    let type, uri: String?
}


//function
func getRecentPlayed(miliTime: String) {
        //let miliTime = "1676369852305"
        let urlString = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played?limit=10&before=\(miliTime)"

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
      
        let urlSessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        urlSessionConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(OAuthToken)"]
        
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: urlSessionConfig)
        let sessionTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            
            if (error == nil && data != nil) {
                let jsondecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let recentPlayedData = try? jsondecoder.decode(Recent.self, from: data!)
                print (recentPlayedData)
                recent = recentPlayedData
            } else {
                print (error)
            }
        }
        sessionTask.resume()
    }
```

What I want:
Run the following loop in swiftui but it screams saying

```
"Referencing initializer on 'ForEach' requires that 'Item' conform to 'Identifiable"
```

```
//swiftui
@State var recent: Recent?

if let r = recent {
       NavigationView {
            List {
                 ForEach(r.items!) { item in
                            Text((item.track?.name)!)
                 }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Recently played")
       }
}
```

Any idea anyone?

Comment: Don't `try?`, never `try?`, you ignore significant information; `catch` the error and print it. It tells you *keyNotFound*. You have to add `CodingKeys` and omit `id`. And why is everything optional? Especially declaring `id` optional is pointless.

Comment: `id` is omitted. i'm not getting any error, but it's asking for identifiable if I want to use the object with `ForEach`. I'll try to add CodingKeys and let you know

Comment: The `id` property of `Identifiable` must be non-optional. Write `let id = UUID()` and add `CodingKeys`.

Comment: I tried it with `CodingKeys` enum and it worked as well. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use what you have that is already unique

```
    struct Recent: Codable {
        var id: String?{
            href
        }
        let items: [Item]?
        let next: String?
        let limit: Int?
        let href: String?
    }
    struct Item: Codable, Identifiable {
        var id:String?{
            track?.id
        }
        let track: Track?
        let played_at: String?
    }
    struct Track: Codable, Identifiable {    //or Codable, Identifiable
        var id: String?{
            uri
        }
        let name: String?
        let popularity: Int?
        let trackNumber: Int?
        let type, uri: String?
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked! That was very smart to be honest. Have a good one :)

Comment: @ccmsd18 glad to help do you mind clicking on the green checkmark to accept the answer and maybe upvoting?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible exactly as you want, I think that the closest thing to what you want is this:

```
struct Track: Codable, Identifiable{    //or   
    let id = UUID() //or something else, it is not clear what is your id  
    let name: String?
    let popularity: Int?
    let trackNumber: Int?
    let type, uri: String?
}
```